# Generating permutations of a set with controlled output?

Tags: matlab, permutation

Is there an easy way to get the first x permutations of a set?

For example a set with 5 characters {a,b,c,d,e} will have

5*5*5*5*5= 3125 permutations output

(repetition is allowed e.g. {a,a,a,a,a})

But I would like to have only the first 100 values for example

Comment: What would you consider the "first" x permutations?  e.g. 100 random possible permutations, or permutations in some order? Also, given your maths, do you mean that {a,a,a,a,a} is an option?

Comment: Yes, {a,a,a,a,a} is an option, yes random is fine

Comment: You should update your question to indicate that, because most `permute`/`perms` etc. permutation functions in MATLAB assume true permutation (no repetition).

Comment: Those are not permutations, but combinations.

Comment: @A.Donda They're permutations because order is significant. `{a,a,b,a,a}` is a different permutation than `{b,a,a,a,a}`. Granted, it is not entirely clear from the question, but given the OP's analysis of the number of possibilities and the accepted answer, I think it's safe to assume they mean permutations.

Comment: @beaker, ok, combinations may not be the right term either, but [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) are rearrangements without changing numbers of occurrences. How about "selections"?

Comment: In [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), you are usually not allowed to use the same item twice. I guess the term you are looking for is a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) or maybe even a [Cartesian power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_power).

Comment: @BasSwinckels Yes, you could call it an element of the Cartesian product of the set, or an n-tuple, but "permutation with repetition" is frequently used.

Comment: @A.Donda See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition

Comment: @beaker, "although they are not permutations in general" :-)

Comment: @A.Donda True, they are not strictly permutations, I will concede that point. :) But the common usage is there, and if you say "permutations with repetition", most people will know precisely what you're looking for, and if you say "n-tuple over the alphabet {...}", they'll generally just blink at you. But `{a, a, a, a, a}` is not a valid permutation (in the strict sense) of `{a, b, c, d, e}`, so we need to find some interpretation that makes the question answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to generate all 'permutations' one at the time in lexicographical order, without having to store them all in memory:

```
function permute_chars(alphabet, nword, nmax)

if nargin < 3  % default to displaying all, this can be a huge number!
    nmax = nchar^nword;
end

nchar = length(alphabet);
ind = zeros(1, nword);
i = 0;

while i < nmax
    % just printing the permutaions, edit according to your needs
    disp(cell2mat(alphabet(ind + 1))); 

    % calculate next indices, classic elementary school addition with carry
    ind(end) = ind(end) + 1;
    for j = nword:-1:2
        if ind(j) == nchar 
            ind(j) = 0;  % wrap around
            ind(j-1) = ind(j-1) + 1;  % carry
        end
    end     
    i = i + 1;
end
```

For sure I am forgetting some obscure function which would allow to implement this in fewer lines, but written like this it is clear how it works. Quick test:

```
>> alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
>> permute_chars(alphabet, 1)
a
b
c
d
e
>> permute_chars(alphabet, 2)
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
ba
[... snip ...]
ed
ee
```

Printing only a limited amount of permutations:

```
>> permute_chars(alphabet, 5, 8)
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
aaaad
aaaae
aaaba
aaabb
aaabc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `P = perms(S)` to get all the permutations of set `S`, and then if you wanted 100 you could do `P(1:100,:)`.

For random you could use `P(randperm(size(P,1),100),:)`.

If you know need to be more specific about the permutations, then you can use `permute` with an `order` parameter - http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html

Comment: Hi crwissy, thing is we will generate a humongous list that if we didn't control it we will run out of memory (e.g. 22^10)

Answer (score 1):

To select 100 random unique samples from numbers `1:n`, with repetitions allowed (sampling with replacement), you can use `randi` or similar to create a list of a bit more than `100 x n` random samples, `unique` them to remove duplicates, and then take the first 100.

For example, using `randi`:

```
% from numbers 1:n, create 200 by n random matrix
sample_list = randi(n,[200, n]);
% remove duplicates
sample_list = unique(sample_list,'rows'); 
% you should probably error check here
% presuming there's >100 options left, take 100 of them
sample_list = sample_list(1:100,:);
```

`sample_list` will be a numeric matrix, but you can easily use it as an index into other things if needed:

```
my_set = {'a','b','c','d','e'}; % 1 x 5 cell
my_permutes = my_set(sample_list); % 100 x 5 cell
```

This avoids having to calculate every single possible option, which for larger `n` would become problematic.

Answer (score 1):

For a bit more flexibility in which range of permutations you get, you can use a function that, given a permutation, produces the next permutation in the series. In this implementation I've chosen to have the permutations wrap back around to the first, even if the input permutation is out of range.

```
function newperm = nextPerm(oldperm, base)
   if any(oldperm >= base)
      newperm = zeros(1,numel(oldperm));
      return
   end
   idx = numel(oldperm);
   newperm = oldperm;
   while idx > 0
      newperm(idx) = newperm(idx) + 1;
      if newperm(idx) < base
         return;
      end
      newperm(idx) = 0;
      idx = idx - 1;
   end
end
```

Permutation elements are 0-based (so max element is base-1).

```
p = [4 4 4 4 4]
nextPerm(p, 5)
ans =

   0   0   0   0   0

p = [0 0 0 0 0]
nextPerm(p, 5)
ans =

   0   0   0   0   1

p = [3 4 1 0 2]
nextPerm(p, 5)
ans =

   3   4   1   0   3

p = [3 4 5 0 2] %// invalid value '5'
nextPerm(p, 5)
ans =

   0   0   0   0   0
```

To get a range, just feed it through a loop:

```
myPerms = zeros(5);
myPerms(1,:) = [3 1 2 0 4];
for k = 2:5
   myPerms(k,:) = nextPerm(myPerms(k-1,:), size(myPerms,1));
end

myPerms =

   3   1   2   0   4
   3   1   2   1   0
   3   1   2   1   1
   3   1   2   1   2
   3   1   2   1   3
```

To map the permutation to your alphabet, just add 1 to the vector and use it as an index:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
word = alphabet(myPerms(1,:)+1)

word = dbcae
```